# Basic drag and drop method in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Does anyone here have a basic tutorial about drag and drop of element in jQuery UI, like image, text, etc. I really appreciate your help and I really need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knock yourself out:

http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/

Comment: @FrancisCebu: this is not the way of say thanks in stackoverflow site. if the answer is helpful please click the upvote and if the answer is best click the right mark to accept answer
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You can go through following samples. it contains 25 ways to do this.

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/04/jquery-drag-drop-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using jQuery  , You may conside [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#default) library. It is simple to implement as this

```
<div class="demo">      
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
     <p>Drag me to my target</p>
  </div>
  <div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
     <p>Drop here</p>
  </div>    
</div>
 <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            $( this )
                .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                .find( "p" )
                    .html( "Dropped!" );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```